# Retraction $S^2 \vee S^4 \rightarrow S^2$ collapsing $S^4$ to the wedge point induces homomorphism on second cohomology.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $r: S^2 \vee S^4 \rightarrow S^2$ be the retraction collapsing $S^4$ to the wedge point. I am trying to show that the induced map $r^{*}: H^{2}(S^2) \rightarrow H^{2}(S^2 \vee S^4)$ on the second cohomology groups is an isomorphism.

We get that it is an injective homomorphism for free because the inclusion map induces a left inverse for $r^{*}$. I need a hint on how to show it is surjective.

Comment: If you think of $S^2\vee S^4$ as a CW-complex with one $0$-cell, one $2$_cell and one $4$-cell etc., then this is immediate on considering cellular cohomology.

Comment: Or the LES of pair $(S^2\vee S^4, S^4)$

Comment: Take the inclusion $S^2\hookrightarrow S^2\vee S^4$ and look at the composition.